# How change percision of float point in matlab treat 5.145556666 as 5.24

Tags: matlab

**updated
I want treat float or double only with 2 digit in float section in matlab.as example

```
a=23.1234443434343434454545444;
```

I want if I use a it is equal

```
a=23.12;
```

any idea  in matlab?

I want funcion like **round(1.95583, 2);//return 1.95** (php function ) in matlab

Comment: is it a matter of screen printing or you want it at the operation level? moreover sum, multiplication and subtraction are fine, what about division, you want it to be truncated too?

Comment: Take a look on fixed-point toolbox.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to *display* values with only 2 digits, you can do

```
>> format bank
>> pi
ans = 
    3.14
>> rand(4)
ans =
      0.81    0.63    0.96    0.96
      0.91    0.10    0.96    0.49
      0.13    0.28    0.16    0.80
      0.91    0.55    0.97    0.14
```

This does ***NOT*** mean calculations will be carried out with less precision.

If the latter is really what you want (why?!), you could use constructions like

```
ppi = single(pi)
```

for *reduced* precision, or

```
f = @(x) double(uint64(x*100))/100;
```

for guaranteed 2-digit precision. In the last case, you have to pass all values through the function `f` prior to using them:

```
>> ppi = f(pi)
ans = 
    3.140000000000000
>> f(rand(4)) 
ans =
   0.280000000000000   0.690000000000000   0.440000000000000   0.190000000000000
   0.050000000000000   0.320000000000000   0.380000000000000   0.490000000000000
   0.100000000000000   0.950000000000000   0.770000000000000   0.450000000000000
   0.820000000000000   0.030000000000000   0.800000000000000   0.650000000000000
```

If you're looking for a more elegant solution for this last case, use the fixed-point toolbox, as Danil suggested.

Comment: Neat solution (+1). I've always used `fix` in the past (as per the answer of @sigma (also +1)). To answer the "why?!" part of your question, perhaps the OP is simulating systems that are subject to [Quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just keep N digits, another formulation is:

```
>> d = 10^(-2)
>> round(pi/d)*d
ans =
    3.1400
```

#### Edit:

As per Rody's comment, round might not truncate properly, so use:

```
>> a = 3.146
>> fix(a/d)*d
ans =
    3.1400
```

Comment: +1, however, there's a subtle difference: casting to `int` drops all digits after the 2nd one indiscriminately, whereas `round` might also change the 2nd digit in case the 3rd digit is 5 or larger.

Comment: Whoops, daily vote limit reached...well, first thing tomorrow then :p

Comment: @Rody: You're right, but your edit does not work as intended. I think it can be fixed by also using `fix` (see edit)?